# How to use res.send in passport strategy?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to make Node.js ajax authentication with passport.js, I want to show messages in `/login` page. I should use `res.send` in my passport strategy, then ajax call ended successfully will display success data to its page. But I can't guess how can I use res. in strategy. Please see below code,

**login.ejs**

```
<div id="messages"></div>

<!-- and there is a form, when form submitted, the ajax call executed.-->
<!-- ...ajax method : POST, url : /login, data: {}, success:... -->
<!-- If ajax call success, get 'result' data and display it here -->
```

**app.js**

```
// and here is ajax handler 
// authentication with received username, password by ajax call

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), 
function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/');
});

// and here is passport strategy 

    passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy(function(userid, password, done) {
  Members.findOne({'user_id' : userid}, function(err, user){

    // if user is not exist
    if(!user){

        // *** I want to use 'res.send' here. 
        // *** Like this : 
        // *** res.send('user is not exist');
        // *** If it is possible, the login.ejs display above message.  
        // *** That's what I'm trying to it. How can I do it?

        return done(null, null);
    }

    // if everything OK,
    else {
        return done(null, {id : userid});
    }

  })


}));
```

I searched some document on google, people usually use 'flash()' in connect-flash module, but I thought this module needed to reload page, this is not what I want to, So please help me and let me know if there is better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of directly inserting the Passport middleware, you can use a custom callback in order to pass the `req, res, next` objects to the Passport function.

You could do something similar in your route handler/controller (this is taken directly from the Passport docs):

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: +1 (I think this separation of concern is preferable over having the Passport middleware handle responses directly)

Comment: If I change the code to like yours, I think I couldn't use failure handler diverse. isn't it? If the messages are 2 kind of ('Wrong password'), ('The ID is not exist'), I couldn't use that. But only can handle ('User is not exist') because It determined to `user object` by passport strategy exist or not. right?